# Переадресация пользователя в папку, если её имя есть в урле

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

Содержание `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([-/_a-zA-Z0-9\s]*)$  index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
DirectoryIndex  index.php
```

Если в урле было `admin/`, как сделать переадресацию в папку `admin`, вместо записи "admin" в переменную `$_GET['page']`

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^admin [NC]
RewriteRule ^dir/index\.php$ /new/sef/? [R=301,L]
```